How to link PROJ lib in C++ cmakelist?
Hiii, I'm still learning C++ and struggling.
I'm trying to use PROJ to transform CRS in C++, and I used sudo apt-get install libproj-dev to download proj.
I tried to link to proj as https://proj.org/en/9.4/development/cmake.html suggested:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(transform_crs)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)


find_package(PROJ REQUIRED CONFIG)


add_executable(transform_crs main.cpp)


target_link_libraries(transform_crs PRIVATE PROJ::proj)

It gives error:
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "PROJ" with any of
  the following names:

    PROJConfig.cmake
    proj-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "PROJ" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "PROJ_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "PROJ"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.

Any idea on how to link the proj in cmakelist? Thank you do much for your help ^O^!

I don't know about PROJ but normally when you get this error (can happen on any library and is very common) you do as it says.

Looks like that file should exist: https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/blob/master/cmake/ProjConfig.cmake

According to https://packages.debian.org/en/sid/amd64/libproj-dev/filelist, libproj-dev should also install CMake config files of proj under /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/proj/ (assuming amd64 architecture), so it should work out of the box without manipulation of CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. Clear your CMake cache and try again maybe? Or try find_package(proj REQUIRED CONFIG) instead, I don't remember whether search procedure is case sensitive regarding sub folders described in https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#config-mode-search-procedure

@drescherjm Thank you for your answer ^V^!  I used sudo apt to download other libraries and they work just fine. I never met find_package() error, It makes me so confused.

@SpacePotatoes Thank youuu ^ ^! Yes I checked the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake, however, it doesn't have anything connected to proj. I tried both methods but it doesn't seem to work. Thank you for your help anyways ^V^

Did you install the libproj-dev package?

@drescherjm Yes I did :>, I used sudo apt-get install libproj-dev and it's indeed installed. I checked the list. So it's really confusing for me.
